# Default RunAs also when opening hyperlinks

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, runas

I can open a browser under a different user using "runas" inside the shortcut target like this:

runas.exe /user:username /savecred pathtobrowserexe

However, I would like this to be the default for this user, not only when opening Chrome with that special shortcut, so in case the user clicks on a link in an email for instance, it should also run the browser under different user credentials (the same user as above). Is there any way to do this? I tried hacking the registry (HKCU\Software\Classes\https\open\command) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Each user has a different default browser, you will need to get this information first. Or do you want the other user to use the current user's browser?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings and search "default. Click default apps and go from there.

At the bottom of the default apps menu there's also options to choose default apps by filetype and protocol.